# Redirect problem when sending authentication request to keycloak

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a Spring Boot + Angular app that I'm deploying with JHipster and Keycloak, and I'm having an issue with User Authentication with Keycloak. On the web service I have a login service that's meant to take in a request and redirect it to the OIDC authentication, but it seems that when the request is sent through keycloak, the URL is rewritten. This causes a bad URL call that results in an Error 404 response. Does anyone know what  might be the solution to this issue?

Here's a sample of the loginservice that forms the redirect URI:

```
        // if on platform1
        if( location.hostname !== "localhost"){
            location.href = '//' + location.hostname + port + '/portal/oauth2/authorization/oidc';
        }else{
            location.href = '//' + location.hostname + port + '/oauth2/authorization/oidc';
        }
```

The running instance should send a URL redirect to `/portal/oauth2/authorization/oidc`, but it doesn't and instead sends to `/oauth2/authorization/oidc`. Following the request/response in real time shows that the app sends the correct URL to redirect, but the keycloak connection returns a malformed URL to the client

I've added the /portal/, /portal/login and /portal/oauth2 as valid redirect URIs in keycloak realms > clients configuration

We've added a `SecurityConfiguration` class in Spring Boot to add the redirect URI

```
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) {
        clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("portal-view")
                .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("portal-view"))
                .scopes("resource:read")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .redirectUris("https://testproxy.spacecamp.ninja/portal/");
```

Even when we manually put in the correct URL, as in the redirect_uri has `/portal` in it, the next page it brings you to is an error 404

Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that client configuration is proper at the keycloak server? Check the client's redirect url property in keycloak server.

Comment: Are you deploying in a tomcat/app server? Wondering what the context path `/portal` is.